# Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) in certEnroll.createFilePFX

Tags: c#, .net, com, cryptography

I'm trying to create CSR and get it signed by CA server using XEnroll COM component available into winxp/2003.

The code I'm using is:

```
XENROLLLib.CEnroll certEnroll = new XENROLLLib.CEnroll();
certEnroll.createFilePFX("Hello", @"D:\testCSR.txt");      //<-- Error here
```

When I execute createFilePFX i get this exception:

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

What could be causing this?

Comment: This is absolutely unhelpful.  Edit your post according to SO guidelines.  You need to give much more info.